# How do you simplify $n!-(n-1)!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

I'm unsure how to simplify the expression $n!-(n-1)!$.

Working as well as the final answer would be preferable.

Comment: See Dominik's hint. For extra credit, simplify $n(n! + (n-1)!)$ :)

Answer (score 12):

**Hint:** $n! = n \cdot (n - 1)!$.

Answer (score 1):

$n!$ is defined inductively by $0!=1$ and $n!=n\cdot(n-1)!$ for $n\geqslant 1$. Hence
$$n! - (n-1)! = n\cdot(n-1)! - (n-1)! = (n-1)(n-1)! $$

Comment: Seems like we have a downvoter on our hands @Battani

Comment: Not the downvoter, but some people downvote because they think you shouldn't completely answer homework questions that show no effort.

Comment: @wythagoras I'm quite aware. But if the question requires very little effort on my end, I'm going to answer it anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

$$n!-(n-1)!=n(n-1)!-(n-1)!=(n-1)!\left( n-1 \right)  $$